# Why are the summands here "inversion preserving"?

Tags: terminology, definition

I am reading Steele's *Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class*, and am wondering what "inversion preserving" refers to the following exercise from Chapter 1:

> **Exercise 1.6 (A Sum of Inversion Preserving Summands)** Suppose that $p_k>0$ for $1\leq k\leq n$ and $\sum_{k=1}^np_k=1$. Show that
> $$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(p_k+\frac1{p_k}\right)^2\geq n^3+2n+\frac1n.$$

So, what "inversion" leaves the summands $(p + 1/p_k)^2$'s unchanged?